# Delete an user from auth_user table in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have to delete an user from auth_user table. And I am trying to do using from django. I am getting

**ProgrammingError: (1146, u"Table 'oculus.auth_user_groups' doesn't exist")**

The code I am using is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.filter(id=3306)
user[0].delete()
```

@EDIT: auth_user_groups table was missing from my db. Got fixed it.

Comment: I am not sure what happens when you filter for an exact id, but I recommend changing the code to: user = User.objects.get(id=3306), and then **user.delete()**

Comment: Even that is also not working. Same error. @dentemm

Comment: are you sure you have applied `migrations`.

Comment: Are you using a custom user model? If so, you should be importing that, rather than `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

Comment: @Alasdair : no, I am not using Custom user model.

Comment: @Bijoy: I will confirm that.

Answer (score 3):

This might help dont use [0].directly use this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.filter(id=3306)
user.delete()
```